# Convert a group of letters into a date in excel

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel

I'm trying to convert a lettered date code into a date.
Example: `SWITCHGEAR = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 & 0`. So when I enter a combination of the letters "`SIRISC`" it would read `13/03/14`. I have tried nearly everything so can someone please point me in the right direction.

Comment: What have you tried? A script solution as well? Show please what have you already achieved.

Comment: I have tried Vlookup but I had to the numbers and letters individually as I couldn't amalgamate the numbers into 1 cell to show a date. I have not thought about a script, I'll have a try.

Comment: before posting at Superuser try a solution and share it to help complete what are you looking for.

Comment: Use a bunch of nested `substitute` functions.

Comment: Are you always using 6 letters? How is 1st Jan 2015 represented?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an array formula solution. For text code in `A1`, enter in another cell by pasting into the formula bar and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
=TEXT(SUM(MOD(FIND(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1),"SWITCHGEAR"),10)*10^(LEN(A1)-ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))))),"00"&CHAR(34)&"/"&CHAR(34)&"00"&CHAR(34)&"/"&CHAR(34)&"00")
```

Breaking it down:

`FIND(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1),"SWITCHGEAR")` generates an array of index numbers that match where in `SWITCHGEAR` each letter of the code in A1 is found. For your example, `SIRISC` generates the array `{1,3,10,3,1,5}`.

By wrapping this expression in `MOD(...,10)`, the array becomes `{1,3,0,3,1,5}`.

This array is then multiplied by the array `{10^5,10^4,10^3,10^2,10^1,10^0}` to generate the array `{100000,30000,0,300,10,5}`.

`SUM` is then used to add the numbers in this array to form `130315`.

`TEXT` is then used to apply the custom format `00"/"00"/"00` so this number is displayed as `13/03/15`.

Comment: Nice! If there will always be 6 letters in A1 you could simplify to this non-array version `=TEXT(SUMPRODUCT(MOD(FIND(MID(A1,{1,2,3,4,5,6},1),"SWITCHGEAR"),10),10^{5,4,3,2,1,0}),"00-00-00")+0` to return an actual date

Comment: ....or you can even get rid of MOD function if you do it like this: `=TEXT(SUMPRODUCT(FIND(MID(A1,{1,2,3,4,5,6},1),"RSWITCHGEA")-1,10^{5,4,3,2,1,0}),"0-00-00")+0`

Answer (score 0):

Select the cells containing the letter combinations and run this small macro:

```
Option Base 1
Sub DateMaker()
    Dim r As Range
    a = Array("S", "W", "I", "T", "C", "H", "G", "E", "A", "R")
    b = Array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0")
    For Each r In Selection
        t = r.Text
        For i = 1 To 10
            t = Replace(t, a(i), b(i))
        Next i
        r.Value = DateSerial(CInt("20" & Right(t, 2)), CInt(Mid(t, 3, 2)), CInt(Left(t, 2)))
        r.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yy"
    Next r
End Sub
```

So if you start with:

[image]

You would end up with:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that:

1. The text SIRISC is in `A1`.
2. In *Sheet2 A1* you have to put `RSWITCHGEA`

Then, try this formula on cell *Sheet1 B1*:

```
=CONCATENATE(FIND(MID(A1,1,1),Sheet2!A1,1)-1,FIND(MID(A1,2,1),Sheet2!A1,1)-1,"/",FIND(MID(A1,3,1),Sheet2!A1,1)-1,FIND(MID(A1,4,1),Sheet2!A1,1)-1,"/",FIND(MID(A1,5,1),Sheet2!A1,1)-1,FIND(MID(A1,6,1),Sheet2!A1,1)-1)
```